# Can't connect to .onion pages, browser is configured to use Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, mac

The Tor 'check' site says my browser is configured to use Tor.  Everything seems to work OK when I browser regular sites, except I can't get to any .onion pages.  For any .onion page I get an error that says "server not found".  I've tried changing proxy settings and the Tor options on launch with no luck.  There is an icon to the left of the nav bar that says 'Tor Disabled' if I hover over the icon, but clicking the button doesn't show any option to enable.  Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up an option "Use proxy to resolve hostnames" - your dot-onion DNS resolve must not go to your ISP's DNS servers, tor SOCKS backend must resolve *all* names all by itself